# static final method in Java

Tags: java, overriding

Java don't let static method of a class to get overridden. So If a Super class method is static, in Sub Class same name method also needs to be static with same signature in order to compile, though it not a method overriding. Below is an example:

[image]

But my question is, so if this is not method overriding, then why can't I make the static method in Super Class final?

[image]

Comment: because you have already declared the foo() method of your super class as "final" that is what "final" keyword is supposed to do.

Comment: [Don't post images of code.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: The duplicate is not relevant to the question, since the OP already knows static methods can't be overridden and is not asking about that (he's asking why the final modifier in the super-class static method prevents a sub-class from defining a static method with same signature, which is not overriding). I'm voting to re-open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at [**JLS 8.4.3.3 final Methods**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3.3), you'll see that the `final` method modifier prevents methods from either being overridden **or hidden**.

> A method can be declared final to prevent subclasses from overriding **or hiding** it.
>
> It is a compile-time error to attempt to override **or hide** a final method.

A `static` method cannot be overridden, but it can be **hidden**. The `final` modifier prevents it from being hidden by a sub-class `static` method.

Comment: Thanks @Eran for correctly getting to the point I wanted to make and your answer helped me to understand method hiding very precisely.

Comment: Hi, I am also trying to understand that in which case we use static final both as both can't be override ... what do we mean by hidden here? as the function is public how it can be hidden